# AngularJS one-time binding with checking array length

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use one-time binding when displaying some content to user if there are any values in array.

I'm using this code:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  loadHeroes = function() {
    $scope.heroes = ['Superman', 'Batman', 'Spider-Man'];
  };

  $timeout(loadHeroes, 5000);

});
```

And this:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <pre ng-show="::heroes.length > 2">There are a few heroes!</pre>
  <pre>{{::heroes | json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Here is Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/k1kxutLd8fOWSoXc81sk?p=preview

But message is not showing. I tried to set parentheses around array, but it's not working either.

Any idea how can I achieve one-time binding with checking array length?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal that's the syntax for one time binding

Comment: as far as I know one-time binding is only delay if the value evaluate to "undefined", so in your case that can evaluate to "false", which would stop watching.

Comment: you can try this way - `::heroes.length > 2 ? true : undefined` - http://plnkr.co/edit/4hCi7hRXpDNSaWTkBmOF?p=preview

Comment: before timeout trigger, heroes is undefined, and heroes.length is undefined in angular, undefined > 2 evaluate to false in javascript. but "false" is "defined", so angular stop watching at that point, and ng-show get false, so it never show.

Comment: @YOU thanks, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, some answers are solving my question, it's good to know what is the actual reason of the behaviour described in question.

Thanks to user @YOU for his comments to question, and clarifying the subject. Below, his explanation with some formatting.

So, in initial state `heroes` is `undefined`, and `heroes.length` is `undefined` in AngularJS as well. In Javascript `undefined > 2` evaluates to `false`. But `false` is `defined`, so Angular stop watching at that point, and `ng-show` get `false`, so it never show.

Solution in this case can be explicit expression `ng-show="::heroes.length > 2 ? true : undefined"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-if` :

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
  loadHeroes = function () {
    $scope.heroes = ['Superman', 'Batman', 'Spider-Man'];
  };
  
  $timeout(loadHeroes, 5000);
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <pre ng-if="::heroes.length">There are a few heroes!</pre>
    <pre>{{::heroes | json}}</pre>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

It will "wait" for the variable to be set.

http://plnkr.co/edit/SMBSMhMPUlRFaRBN0xtb?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

[The syntax `::`](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/speeding-up-angular-js-with-simple-optimizations/135):

> render data once and let it persist without being affected by future
>   Model updates

The `$scope` value is not updated, so your view is not updated after the `$timeout`.

Removing this syntax works for `ng-show` http://jsfiddle.net/2ctyjfk0/:

```
angular.module('Joy', [])
    .controller('IfCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.names = ['Joy', 'Elit', 'Carl'];
    }, 3000);
}]);
```

Html:

```
<div ng-app="Joy">
    <div ng-controller="IfCtrl">
        <div ng-show="names">Names: {{ names | json }}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [`ng-if`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf). It is working in your case because:

> `ngIf` differs from `ngShow` and `ngHide` in that ngIf completely removes and recreates the element in the DOM...Note that when an element is removed using `ngIf` its scope is destroyed and a new scope is created when the element is restored.

If removing/inserting the DOM elements is acceptable for you, choose `ng-if`.